# Copy innerHTML of Span element using browser console

Tags: html, console

How would you copy the text content from within a  element to the clipboard using the web console?

what command would be entered into the console?

```
<span id="example">Example text string</span>
```

I think its something like document.getElementById('example') any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should type console.log in order to print any thing in the live editor (Console).
Beside this if you are willing to print document.getElementbyId('example'). then you should carefully follow the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById 
Hope to see your problem get solved.
Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

To get the innerHTML of any element, 
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML;
You can print the innerHTML contents to console by using console.log(document.getElementById('example').innerHTML)